# How to style td using javascript without using id and class..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, html-parsing

Hi I am having HTML like this...

```
<table width="600">
<tr>
  <td>
     Text
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
     <img src="demo.jpg" width="200" height="200"/>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="font:arial;">
     <img src="demo.jpg" width="200" height="200"/>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="font:arial;">
   <a href="#">
     <img src="demo.jpg" width="200" height="200"/>
   </a>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

i am using the following function to add style="font-size:0%" in all the td's having images.

```
function change(input, output) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    try {
        div.innerHTML = input;
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
        return;
    }

var table = div.getElementsByTagName("table"),
    tds = div.getElementsByTagName("td"),
    tdsWithImages = Array.prototype.slice.call(tds).filter(function (td) {
        return td.getElementsByTagName('img').length > 0
    });
    tdsWithImages.map(function (td) {
        td.style.fontSize = "0%";
    });
    output.value = div.innerHTML;
}
```

The style attribute is overwritten.
i.e style="font:arial;" will be overwrited to style="font-size:0%;" in all the td's having images.

But it should be style="font:arial; font-size:0%;"

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest than rather than using direct style element and manipulate it using javascript you just  use css classes, it's also the proper way to do things rather than inline your styles.
I'd also suggest you move your font style to another (or same) class.

css:

```
.zero_font_size {
   font-size:0%
}
```

javascript:

```
var tds = document.getElementByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
  tds[i].className = tds[i].className + "zero_font_size";
}
```

javascript ECMAScript5 (new browsers)

```
var tds = document.getElementByTagName("td");
tds.forEach(function(td) {
    td.className = tds.className + "zero_font_size";
});
```

or if you want to use inline styles:

```
var tds = document.getElementByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
  tds[i].cssText = tds[i].cssText + ";font-size:0%";
}
```

Comment: the script will work, but we are not using any ID's and class in newsletter development..
i want that to be inlined in td which are having images..

Comment: In newsletter development for fixing issue in Outlook we need to use style="font-size:0%" in all td's having images. there is no support for style @ the head section for Outlook. it will simply ignore..

Answer (score 0):

What about using JQUERY script? DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/MGRcA/2/

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('td').find('img').map(function(){
        $(this).parent('td').css({'font-size':'0%', 'font-family':'arial'});
    });
});
```

## HTML

```
<table width="600">
<tr>
  <td>
     Text
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
     <img src="demo.jpg" width="200" height="200"/>Text
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="font:arial;">
     <img src="demo.jpg" width="200" height="200"/>Text
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="font:arial;">
   <a href="#">
     <img src="demo.jpg" width="200" height="200"/>Text
   </a>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The above code will work, but it will fail in 3rd case i.e for the image wrapped with anchor tag and the above html is just an example. Td includes so many other styles, with different font family..